# How to remove item from list in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-core, generic-collections

I have a list stored in resultlist as follows:

```
var resultlist = results.ToList();
```

It looks something like this:

```
ID FirstName  LastName
-- ---------  --------
1  Bill       Smith
2  John       Wilson
3  Doug       Berg
```

How do I remove ID 2 from the list?

Answer (score 516, accepted):

`List<T>` has [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35412369/1016343) methods you can use.

[RemoveAt(int index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) can be used if you know the index of the item. For example:

```
resultlist.RemoveAt(1);
```

Or you can use [Remove(T item)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx):

```
var itemToRemove = resultlist.Single(r => r.Id == 2);
resultList.Remove(itemToRemove);
```

When you are not sure the item really exists you can use [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549274.aspx). `SingleOrDefault` will return `null` if there is no item (`Single` will throw an exception when it can't find the item). Both will throw when there is a duplicate value (two items with the same `id`).

```
var itemToRemove = resultlist.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == 2);
if (itemToRemove != null)
    resultList.Remove(itemToRemove);
```

Comment: well, than maybe `var itemsToRemove = resultlist.Where(r => r.Id == 2); foreach (var itemToRemove in ItemsToRemove) resultList.Remove(itemToRemove);`

Comment: Shouldn't this be `resultlist.Items.RemoveAt(1);` ?

Answer (score 115):

#### Short answer:

###### Remove (from list `results`)

`results.RemoveAll(r => r.ID == 2);` will remove the item with **ID 2** in `results` (in place).

(the other two possible remove methods are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019009/1016343))

###### Filter (without removing from original list `results`):

`var filtered = results.Where(f => f.ID != 2).ToList();` returns all items except the one with **ID 2**, which are then accessible via the `filtered` variable. The `results` list is not touched and still contains all list items.

 **Important:** Variable `filtered` **does not** contain copies of the original objects, instead it refers to the same objects as the original list (except that some are filtered out). Hence you can still manipulate them through both variables (here in this example, filtered[0] and results[0] would refer to the same item, because the first item wasn't filtered out - the filtering occured on the 2nd item in the list which has ID==2).

#### Detailed answer:

I think **`.RemoveAll()`** is very flexible, because you can have a list of item IDs which you want to remove - please regard the following example.

If you have:

```
class myClass {
    public int ID; public string FirstName; public string LastName;
}
```

and assigned some values to `results` as follows (used for all examples below):

```
var results = new List<myClass> {
    new myClass { ID=1, FirstName="Bill", LastName="Smith" },   // results[0]
    new myClass { ID=2, FirstName="John", LastName="Wilson" },  // results[1]
    new myClass { ID=3, FirstName="Doug", LastName="Berg" },    // results[2]
    new myClass { ID=4, FirstName="Bill", LastName="Wilson" }   // results[3]
};
```

Then you can define a list of IDs to remove:

```
var removeList = new List<int>() { 2, 3 };
```

And simply use this to remove them:

```
results.RemoveAll(r => removeList.Any(a => a==r.ID));
```

It will **remove the items 2 and 3** and keep the items 1 and 4 - as specified by the `removeList`. **Note** that this happens in place, so there is no additional assigment required.

Of course, you can also use it on single items like:

```
results.RemoveAll(r => r.ID==4);
```

where it will remove Bill with ID 4 in our example.

A last thing to mention is that lists have an indexer, that is, they can also be accessed like a dynamic array, i.e. `results[3]` will give you the 4th element in the results list (because the first element has the index 0, the 2nd has index 1 etc).

So if you want to remove all entries where the first name is the same as in the 4th element of the results list, you can simply do it this way:

```
results.RemoveAll(r => results[3].FirstName == r.FirstName);
```

Note that afterwards, only John and Doug will remain in the list, Bill is removed (the first and last element in the example). Important is that the list will shrink automatically, so it has only 2 elements left - and hence the largest allowed index after executing RemoveAll in this example is 1 
(which is `results.Count() - 1`).

**Some Trivia:**
You can use this knowledge and create a local function

```
void myRemove()  { var last = results.Count() - 1; 
                   results.RemoveAll(r => results[last].FirstName == r.FirstName); }
```

What do you think will happen, if you call this function twice?

Like

```
myRemove(); myRemove();
```

(Assuming the list `results` contains all 4 elements as declared before you call the function twice)

**Answer** (click to show):

> The first call will remove Bill at the first and last position, the second call will remove Doug and only John Wilson remains in the list.

---

**Note:** Since [C# Version 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8), you can as well write `results[^1]` which means 
`results[results.Count() - 1]`, i.e. the function above looks much simpler:

```
void myRemove()  =>  results.RemoveAll(r => results[^1].FirstName == r.FirstName);
```

So you would not need the local variable `last` anymore (see [indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)). Furthermore, since it is a one-liner, you don't require the curly braces and can use `=>` instead.
For a list of all the new features in C#, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history).

---

DotNetFiddle: [Run the demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6p8cmi)

Answer (score 50):

```
resultList = results.Where(x=>x.Id != 2).ToList();
```

There's a little Linq helper I like that's easy to implement and can make queries with "where not" conditions a little easier to read:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    return source.Where(x=>!predicate(x));
}

//usage in above situation
resultList = results.ExceptWhere(x=>x.Id == 2).ToList();
```

Comment: Another similar approach (that uses a predicate) is to use `List.FindIndex`/`List.RemoteAt` (which has the "nice" or "not so nice" feature of being a mutating operation).

Comment: True, but be careful about saying that List's operation *is* mutating. List uses an array behind the scenes, and it can recreate its array with a smaller or larger capacity when it thinks that's necessary. *Usually*, removal is an in-place mutation of the existing array.

Comment: This isnt thread safe, and for its simplicity you can just use SingleOrDefault, it doesnt need to be contained in a static method

Comment: Nobody said it was thread-safe (and whether it is depends on what the threads are supposed to be doing; it may in fact be preferable to give a different in-memory construct to a worker thread versus letting them all work on one concurrent collection), and the OP wants all records *except* the one matching the predicate, so SingleOrDefault would in fact return exactly what they *don't* want. The "static method" is in fact an extension method, like most of Linq, and it works whenever what you don't want (one element or many) is easier to define than what you do.

Comment: fyi: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0

Comment: @edelwater - Good addition, however the use cases are different; Except() takes an IEnumerable of specific exceptional instances of the generic enumerated type, and returns an enumerable that does not contain any instances of the source enumerable that are "equal" to any exception, as determined by the default equality comparer. My code makes the conditional determination based on a predicate function, which can differ from any equality comparison of the object(s) in the enumerable.

Comment: If comparer is null, the default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values.

Answer (score 7):

You don't specify what kind of list, but the generic List can use either the `RemoveAt(index)` method, or the `Remove(obj)` method:

```
// Remove(obj)
var item = resultList.Single(x => x.Id == 2);
resultList.Remove(item);

// RemoveAt(index)
resultList.RemoveAt(1);
```

Answer (score 6):

There is another approach. It uses [`List.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9.aspx) and `List.RemoveAt`.

While  I would *probably* use the solution presented by KeithS (just the simple `Where`/`ToList`) this approach differs in that it *mutates* the original list object. This can be a good (or a bad) "feature" depending upon expectations.

In any case, the `FindIndex` (coupled with a guard) ensures the `RemoveAt` will be correct if there are gaps in the IDs or the ordering is wrong, etc, and using `RemoveAt` (vs `Remove`) avoids a *second* O(n) search through the list.

Here is a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.org) snippet:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 3, 2 };
var index = list.FindIndex(i => i == 2); // like Where/Single
if (index >= 0) {   // ensure item found
    list.RemoveAt(index);
}
list.Dump();        // results -> 1, 3
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 6):

More simplified:

```
resultList.Remove(resultList.Single(x => x.Id == 2));
```

there is no needing to create a new var object.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
resultlist.Remove(resultlist.Find(x => x.ID == 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

... or just `resultlist.RemoveAt(1)` if you know exactly the index.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mutate the original `List<T>` with [`.RemoveAt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat) but need a new List instead I find this very handy:

```
List<string> originalList = new List<string> { "Bill", "John", "Doug" };
List<string> updatedList = originalList.Where((_, index) => index != 1).ToList();
// { "Bill", "Doug" }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
{
    class Program
    {
        public static List<Product> list;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            list = new List<Product>() { new Product() { ProductId=1, Name="Nike 12N0",Brand="Nike",Price=12000,Quantity=50},
                 new Product() { ProductId =2, Name = "Puma 560K", Brand = "Puma", Price = 120000, Quantity = 55 },
                 new Product() { ProductId=3, Name="WoodLand V2",Brand="WoodLand",Price=21020,Quantity=25},
                 new Product() { ProductId=4, Name="Adidas S52",Brand="Adidas",Price=20000,Quantity=35},
                 new Product() { ProductId=5, Name="Rebook SPEED2O",Brand="Rebook",Price=1200,Quantity=15}};


            Console.WriteLine("Enter ProductID to remove");
            int uno = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var itemToRemove = list.Find(r => r.ProductId == uno);
            if (itemToRemove != null)
                list.Remove(itemToRemove);
            Console.WriteLine($"{itemToRemove.ProductId}{itemToRemove.Name}{itemToRemove.Brand}{itemToRemove.Price}{ itemToRemove.Quantity}");
            Console.WriteLine("------------sucessfully Removed---------------");

            var query2 = from x in list select x;
            foreach (var item in query2)
            {
                /*Console.WriteLine(item.ProductId+" "+item.Name+" "+item.Brand+" "+item.Price+" "+item.Quantity );*/
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.ProductId}{item.Name}{item.Brand}{item.Price}{ item.Quantity}");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?