# c# remove item from list without knowing index number

Tags: c#

I have a list with collection of my object:

```
List<MyObj> list = new List<MyObj>();
```

My function received MyObj as a parameter and i want to remove this object from the list like suggest here: [c# remove item from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018957/c-sharp-remove-item-from-list)

```
    private void remove(MyObj obj)
    {
        var itemToRemove = list.Where(x => x.fileName == obj.fileName);

        if (itemToRemove != null)
            list.Remove(itemToRemove);
    }
```

Compiler error received:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'namespace.MyObj'

Comment: On a related note, I'd recommend not to use the `var` keyword unless you as the developer already know what type it should be.

Comment: Remember that a LINQ query returns an IEnumerable unless you define it otherwise by wrapping it in a `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove item from list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018957/how-to-remove-item-from-list-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Where()` returns an `IEnumerable<>`

Try this:

```
private void remove(MyObj obj)
{
    var itemToRemove = list.Where(x => x.fileName == obj.fileName);

    if (itemToRemove.Any())
        list.Remove(itemToRemove.First());
}
```

Better yet, as you're using `List<>`:

```
list.RemoveAll(x => x.fileName == obj.fileName);
```

**Edit**

Other solutions, that are all equally viable from the comments below.  Pick your poison, though selfishly (and perhaps obviously) I prefer the readability and simplicity of the `RemoveAll` method:

*Knittl:*

```
list = list.Where(x => x.filename != obj.filename).ToList();
```

*Jeroen van Langen*:

```
var itemToRemove = list.Where(x => x.fileName == obj.fileName).FirstOfDefault(); 
if (itemToRemove != null)
    list.Remove(itemToRemove);
```

Comment: Why not just `list = list.Where(x => x.filename != obj.filename).ToList();`?

Comment: @knittl, that is yet another approach, yes, but I don't think it is as readable as to what it is doing. :)

Comment: @knittl - wouldn't it be more efficient to edit a List<> as opposed to creating a new one, especially if there are many items?

Comment: I'd rather use the `var itemToRemove = list.Where(x => x.fileName == obj.fileName).FirstOfDefault();`  `if (itemToRemove != null)`

Comment: Whats the different between go over all my list through loop compare to list.Where(...) ?

Answer (score 3):

You were mixed up between `Where` and `FirstOrDefault`:

```
private void remove(MyObj obj)
{
    var itemToRemove = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.fileName == obj.fileName);
    if (itemToRemove != null)
        list.Remove(itemToRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to implement this method, the remove method of List already performs this operation as expected.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx

```
public bool Remove(
    T item
)
```

Comment: This removes by reference equality, whereas the OP wishes to remove on the properties of the class in question (in this case, `fileName`).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method exposed by list to remove all the matching elements -

```
private void remove(MyObj obj)
{
    var itemToRemove = list.RemoveAll(x => x.fileName == obj.fileName);
}
```