# Remove list items where property = myValue

Tags: c#, .net, list

I've got a problem. I have a list of objects (vehicle).

```
List<Vehicle> vehicleList = Vehicle.GetVehiclesFromDatabase();
```

And now I want something like this:

```
vehicleList.Remove(where vehicleList.Brand == "Volkswagen");
```

I hope I could explain what my problem is.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# remove item from list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018957/c-sharp-remove-item-from-list)

Comment: Try something like this : List<Vehicle>  results = vehicleList.Where(x =>  vehicleList.Brand != "Volkswagen").ToList();

Comment: Use `vehicleList.RemoveAll(item => item.Brand == "Volkswagen");` to remove all items with Volkswagen brand. To remove a single item you need to either pass the item, or know its index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int recordsRemoved = vehicleList.RemoveAll(v => v.Brand == "Volkswagen");
```

The method takes a `Predicate<T>` (= `Func<T,bool>`), which will remove all items for which the predicate returns `true`.

For you this is equal to the following method:

```
bool Filter(Vehicle vehicle)
{
   return vehicle.Brand == "Volkswagen";
}
```

Comment: This will remove all where the brand **isn't** Volkswagen, they want the opposite

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq to do this, like so

```
vehicleList = vehicleList.Where(v => v.Brand != "Volkswagen").ToList();
```

You can also do this with a RemoveAll

```
vehicleList.RemoveAll(v => v.Brand == "Volkswagen");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
var itemToRemove = vehicleList.Single(r => r.Brand ==  "Volkswagen");
resultList.Remove(itemToRemove);
```

When you are not sure the item really exists you can use SingleOrDefault. SingleOrDefault will return null if there is no item (Single will throw an exception when it can't find the item). Both will throw when there is a duplicate value (two items with the same id).

```
var itemToRemove = vehicleList.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Brand ==  "Volkswagen");
if (itemToRemove != null)
    resultList.Remove(itemToRemove);
```