# How to remove multiple objects in List by id?

Tags: c#, list, object, remove-if

I have a class as below

```
class MyClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

I have an array of ids I need to remove:

```
List<myClass> myObjArray = new List<myClass>;

myClass myObj1 = new myClass { id = "1", data = "aaa"};
myClass myObj2 = new myClass { id = "2", data = "bbb"};
myClass myObj3 = new myClass { id = "3", data = "ccc"};
myClass myObj4 = new myClass { id = "4", data = "ddd"};

myObjArray.Add(myObj1);
myObjArray.Add(myObj2);
myObjArray.Add(myObj3);
myObjArray.Add(myObj4);

string [] idToBeRemove = {"1", "3"};
```

Is there any method to remove the myObj in myObjArray where the id is in the idToBeRemove string?

Comment: Have you considered not holding these items in a List? You could hold them in a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) where the Id is the *Key* and the instance of the class is the *Value*. Doing this will improve lookup times compared to List, and you can remove things based on the *Key*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# - How to remove item from list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018957/c-sharp-how-to-remove-item-from-list)

Comment: @SeM this is different than the suggested duplicate: that was for removing one item, this is for removing multiple items. The solution is different.

Comment: @Richardissimo no it isn't, if you look at 3rd answer.

Comment: The duplicate vote is [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377171/should-a-question-be-marked-as-a-duplicate-where-the-question-is-different-but-o).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`List<T>` has a method `RemoveAll` which will accomplish what you need. Unlike doing something like `Where(...).ToList()`, it will modify the existing list in place rather than create a new one.

```
myObjArray.RemoveAll(item => idToBeRemove.Contains(item.id));
```

Note that as your array of items to remove grows, you'll want to move to something more performant, such as a `HashSet<T>`, though with your current count of 2, it is not a pressing need.

[@Richardissimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5198140/richardissimo) also offers a good suggestion in the comments to your question for when the main list itself grows, a `Dictionary<K, V>` could be useful. Again, not an immediate need with a small list, but something to keep in mind as it grows and if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

To remove from existing `List` you can use [List.RemoveAll(Predicate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.List%601.RemoveAll);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
myObjArray.RemoveAll(r => idToBeRemove.Contains(r.id));
```

To get result in new collection you can use [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Enumerable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var result = myObjArray.Where(m => !idToBeRemove.Contains(m.id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var result = myObjArray.Where(m => !idToBeRemove.Contains(m.id)).ToList();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                myObjArray.Remove(item);
            }
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `idToBeRemove.Contains(m.id)` instead of  `!idToBeRemove.Contains(m.id)` ?

Comment: And the `.ToList()` is just causing it to put things in a list, which is unnecessary when it is only going to iterate the enumerable once

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove id:

```
myObjArray.RemoveAll(item => idToBeRemove.Contains(item.id));
```