# Matching specific object item in list with class members

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I need to match items in this list, however, the Players value is not always known.
How can I exclude the Players from the myMembers.Contains match ?
Or, how can I only search by ID (which will always be available and unique)?

```
public class Data
{
    public Data(string id, string firstName, string lastName, string players)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.PLayers= players;
    }
    public string Id{set;get;}
    public string FirstName{ set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
    public string Players{ set; get; }
}
```

```
List<Data> myMembers= new List<Data>();
if(myMembers.Contains(new Data(Id, First, Last, Players))
{
   myMembers.Remove(new Data(Id, First, Last, Players));
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019009/8335151) help you?

Comment: What is expected number of items in the list (approximately)?

Comment: @KyleWang yes, the Single method was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Dennis about 10

Comment: Note that, given the code that you've shown, `myMembers.Contains(new Data(Id, First, Last, Players)` is unlikely to ever be `true`. You have no comparer, and you haven't overloaded `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Id is unique, you can simply compare that to find out what should be removed.

```
var match = myMembers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == Id);

If(match != null)
{
   myMembers.Remove(match);
}
```

Comment: thanks this one looks like what I am looking for