# Removing an array of int from a list of type int array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

I intend to have a field of type `List<int[]>` that holds some int array (used in Unity to record some grid positions), looks roughly like:

```
{
 {0, 0},
 {0, 1},
 {0, 2}
}
```

But when I try to remove elements from this list, it seems to be having some difficulty doing so:

```
int[] target = new int[] {0, 0}; 
// Simplified, in the actual code I have to do some calculations. 
// But during debug, I confirmed that the same array I want to remove 
// is in the intArrayList

intArrayList.Remove(target);

// {0, 0} seems to be still here
```

Is that supposed to happen? If so, how can I fix that?

Comment: those are distinct objects in the memory. this is the reason that remove doesn't work. That would work for reference types, such as integers or strings but since the target is an array (a reference type) remove doesn't find the item. I think that locating the index and removing by index would be a best bet.

Comment: Try to read this answer, might be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018957/how-to-remove-item-from-list-in-c

Comment: Does your list have to be of plain old arrays? If not you could make a quasi-array class and override GetHashCode  (perhaps xor ^ all the numbers) and Equals (actually check the equality of each element). Then List.Remove would work.

Comment: "But during debug, I confirmed that the same array I want to remove" this does not look to be true, especially based on the answer that was accepted. Please pay attention to what you observe/report: "the same array" and "array with the same values" are very different things - i.e. the example shown in the question indeed implies that  `intArrayList = new List<int[]>(target, new[]{0,1}, new[]{0,2});` but accepted answer hints otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are deleting a different instance of the same list. Since C# array uses the default equality checker, the instance needs to be the same in order for the other array to get removed.

A quick fix is to write your own method that searches the list for the appropriate array first, and then removing the item at that index:

```
var target =  new int[] {0, 0}; 
var indexToRemove = intArrayList.FindIndex(a => a.SequenceEqual(target));
if (indexToRemove >= 0) {
    intArrayList.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
}
```

A good fix is to stop using the "naked" array: wrap it into your own class with an appropriate comparison semantic, and use that class instead. This would make your code more readable, give you more control over what goes into the array, and let you protect the array from writing if necessary. It will also let you use the original removal code, which is a small bonus on top of the other great things you are going to get for writing a meaningful wrapper on top of the array.

Comment: Dude this SequenceEquals is amazing.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use the correct data structure!

What you have is a little bit like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have an issue with the attempted solution using a bad data structure for what you are actually trying to achieve.

If this is about Unity grid positions as you say, **do not use `int[]` at all!**

Rather simply use [`Vector2Int`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.html) which already provides a structure for two coupled `int` values (coordinates) and implements all the necessary interfaces for successfully compare it for equality:

```
List<Vector2Int> yourList = new List<Vector2Int>()
{
    new Vector2Int(0, 0),
    new Vector2Int(0, 1),
    new Vector2Int(0, 2),
    ...
}

var target = new Vector2Int(0, 1);
yourList.Remove(target);
```

Since `Vector2Int` implements [`IEquatable<Vector2Int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1) and [`GetHashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode) these kind of operations on lists and dictionaries can be done implicit.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove the array by ref and most likely your intention is to remove it by value.

this should work:

```
intArrayList.RemoveAll(p => p[0] == 0 && p[1] == 0);
```

Another option is to use records instead of int[2] arrays since they have built-in implementation of value equality

```
record GridPosition(int X, int Y);
//...
List<GridPosition> intArrayList = new();
intArrayList.Add(new GridPosition(0, 0));
intArrayList.Add(new GridPosition(1, 0));

var target = new GridPosition(0, 0);
intArrayList.Remove(target);
Assert.AreEqual(1, intArrayList.Count);
```